# When converting one inequality to another, do I need to preserve absolute values?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

For example... I need to prove the following limit using "$\epsilon-N$" language

> $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin n}{n}=0$

I've taken the inequality $\left|\frac{\sin n}{n}\right|<\epsilon$ and added a value between the two...

$$\left|\frac{\sin n}{n}\right|<\left|\frac{2}{n}\right|<\epsilon$$

but, assuming I'm even doing this right, I wonder if I need to keep the bars around $\frac{2}{n}$... seeing as that fraction can never be negative...

And somewhat on topic... do I need to find a new fraction that is strictly greater than $\left|\frac{\sin n}{n}\right|$, or can it be less than or equal to? I picked the number 2 because it makes my fraction bigger in all cases, where $1/n$ would fit if I could choose $\leq$.

Comment: $|x|=x$ for $x\geq 0$

Answer (score 1):

Note $\left|\frac{2}{n}\right|=\frac{2}{n}$, as Jean-Sebastien points out. Additionally, $\sin(n)<1$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z$ since $|\sin(x)|=1$ implies $x=(n+\frac{1}{2})\pi$ for some $n\in \Bbb Z$, thus $x$ is irrational.

In general, as long as you have some upper- and lower-bounds (the inequalities need not be strict) that go to the same value, you can determine what your sequence converges to, too. This is know as the squeeze theorem. In this particular case, you know the constant sequence $0$ is a lower bound and $2/n$ is an upper bound. Both converge to $0$, so the sequence in between the values must also go to $0$.